# Deprecation of PHP language versions less than 7.2.5 in the AWS SDK

Tags: php, aws-php-sdk

I recently came across this deprecation warning of the SDK is using PHP version 5.5.38, which will be deprecated on August 15th, 2023.  Please upgrade your PHP version to a minimum of 7.2.5 before then to continue receiving updates to the AWS SDK for PHP.

Before 15 Aug 2023, It was just giving the warning and did not affect code execution. But just after then it stopped executing our code and throwing the same warning messages.

So, what is the quick fix/short-term solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Our application's code was operating with legacy features, making it challenging to swiftly transition from PHP 5 to PHP 7. Given this situation, it was imperative to identify a prompt and effective solution for the issue at hand.

The solution entails introducing a global environment variable and configuring the ***AWS_SUPPRESS_PHP_DEPRECATION_WARNING*** flag to 'true' within a Docker container or the corresponding runtime environment of your code. In my specific scenario, our applications operate within Docker containers.

```
AWS_SUPPRESS_PHP_DEPRECATION_WARNING = true
```

Upon successfully implementing this environmental setup within your application's runtime environment, the problem should cease to manifest.

Comment: This solution only papers over the problem in that AWS may choose to alter their API in a way that is no longer compatible with the version of the PHP library that still runs on your legacy version. At that point it will break in a way that a simple environment variable will not fix. You should also be advised that PHP 7 is EOL as well. You should be targeting a move to 8.x ASAP.